# Weird line in the pmap man page

Tags: unix, sunos, pmap

I was reading the pmap man page, basically, it gives a memory map of a process. But there is an interesting line that caught my attention at the end of the man page:

```
STANDARDS

No standards apply, but pmap looks awful lot like a SunOS command.
```

What does that mean? Why does this similarity matter? How it is relevant to the standards section? It seemed somewhat informal to me, is there some kind of joke? Thanks.

Comment: It means it's _probably_ compatible with SunOS' `pmap` command, but it's not verified.

Comment: Why refer SunOS in this context? Because it was widely used back then?

Comment: The point of standards is compatibility, so it's trying to say what it's compatible with.